# Differences in counted population between raster and polygonized values - QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I'm slightly puzzled with the "polygonize" tool in QGIS. I'm working on population data, and therefore have clipped the NASA SEDAC Population count raster to my country of interest (Mozambique).

When I run the zonal statistics tool, the sum of all pixel values equate to 22'177'510 inhabitants. For the purpose of my analysis, I need to polygonize the pixels so I can move on using vector analysis tools. Therefore I've used the "raster pixels to polygons" in the processing toolbox, this does not ask for the cell size of the raster.

[image]

In the layers properties i have this information for the raster: 
Width   1075
Height  1744

When I run the statistical summary (sigma icon on the toolbar menu) on my new polygonized layer, the pixels value now equate to 22'244'500. It is a slight difference but still, I don't understand this difference. It could be due to a difference in cell dimension, where the tool creates more polygons than pixels, hence this difference in population.
Both layers are projected in UTM Zone38S EPSG 5629.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact procedure you used to convert raster to polygon, including the cell dimensions of your original raster.

Comment: You can use the geometry checker tool to test whether there are any duplicate or overlapping polygons.

Comment: Are you seriously concerned about a difference that is only about 0.3%? Surely it is within the realms of acceptable precision on your analysis. I don't know the process but perhaps it comes about due to how polygonalization addresses boundary values.

Comment: @LeighBettenay, I'm not seriously concerned no, I was just curious of why there was a difference between the two processes. And to understand it.